# Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 4 passed to UsernamePasswordToken::__construct() must be an array, null given

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I am getting the following error when logging in into my Symfony application (with correct username and password):

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 4 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::__construct() must be an array, null given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\essweb\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\UserAuthenticationProvider.php on line 96 and defined in D:\xampp\htdocs\essweb\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken.php line 36

**Security.yml**

```
firewalls:
        admin_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path:  /
                check_path:  /login_check
                default_target_path: /user
                failure_path: /
                #username_parameter: username
                #password_parameter: password
                remember_me: true

            remember_me:
                key: "%secret%"
                lifetime: 31536000
                path: /
                domain: ~
                always_remember_me: true
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
```

Updated:

**Login form:**

```
<form class="form-signin form-group" action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="_username" placeholder="Username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required">
Password: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="_password" placeholder="" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required">
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

Comment: We need to see your form and to know if you had extend the UserBundle' securityController .

Comment: I have not used user bundle. This is just a simple login form

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Basically, what the error message says is:

The 4th argument for [`UsernamePasswordToken::__construct()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/UsernamePasswordToken.php#L36) should be an array, but it's `null`. It was called in [`UserAuthenticationProvider` at line 96](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php#L96).

If you take a look at that code, you'll see that the 4th argument for `UsernamePasswordToken::__construct()` is `$roles`. So that should be an array, but it's getting `null` instead.

I'm guessing that you have [written your own User entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#loading-users-from-the-database), and that the `getRoles()` method of your user entity is returning `null` instead of an array of roles. So just change that method to something like this:

```
/**
 * Returns the roles granted to the user.
 * 
 * @return Role[] The user roles
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return array('ROLE_USER');
}
```

Of course, the actual code may differ (you might want to store the user roles in the database), as long as `getRoles()` returns an array of strings or [Role](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Role/Role.php) objects.

Comment: Please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402312/symfony-login-not-working

How to return roles from databases ? I'm always getting error when I return array of roles on registration page.

Answer (score 4):

I fix this error so returning roles:

```
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles->toArray();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is catching because the roles property current provided value is null however you have to give it an array of roles, so to resolve it just return the roles propoerty :

```
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles;
}
```