# Symfony Login Not working

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I'm using symfony 2.8, I'm new to symfony,I have implemented login and registration, registration is working fine but when I login it showing this error

```
Type error: Argument 4 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, 
called in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\UserAuthenticationProvider.php on line 96
```

Now I'm bit confused in ROLES implementation, I have users table in DB,

**USERS TABLE**

```
id      Primary     int(11)
name                varchar(255)    
email   Index       varchar(255) 
password            varchar(64)
roles               varchar(255) 
created_at          datetime
```

**User Entity**

```
public function setRoles($roles) {
    $this->roles = $roles;
}

public function getRoles() {
        return $this->roles;
}
```

**Security.yml**
firewalls section

```
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
        pattern:    ^/
        http_basic: ~
        provider: our_db_provider
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
        #http_basic: ~

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
        #form_login: ~
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
```

If I change my getRoles function to return array like this

```
public function getRoles() {
    return array('ROLE_USER');
}
```

In this case it is showing error on registration page.

```
The value of type "array" cannot be converted to a valid array key.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 4 passed to UsernamePasswordToken::\_\_construct() must be an array, null given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009476/catchable-fatal-error-argument-4-passed-to-usernamepasswordtoken-construct)

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009476/catchable-fatal-error-argument-4-passed-to-usernamepasswordtoken-construct

Comment: why downvoted. ?

Comment: Don’t mind down votes, you need to get used to it in stackoverflow, a lot of mad people out there, and this makes new comers a little bit offended :/ but what can we possibly do about it! I’ll upvote so it’s back to 0 lol

Comment: Thank you @teeyo. I have gone through questions already that are mentioned above saying possible duplicate of my question. But my problem is different than those questions. I have updated my question so that its more easy to understand now.

Comment: Can you show the code of all your User entity, I need to see its constructor, and maybe you can dump the `$roles` variable there to verify its value.

Comment: Please check User entity here https://gist.github.com/shoebaamir7/abedffdad829557347da34624f0c95b7

Comment: Can you add a constructor to your code and dump the value of roles then try to login and see what gets dumped `public function __construct($username, $password, $salt, array $roles)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->salt = $salt;
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }`

Comment: Now after adding constructor Its showing this error-----  "Type error: Too few arguments to function AppBundle\Entity\User::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\src\AppBundle\Controller\UserController.php on line 56 and exactly 4 expected"

Comment: Yup, because we didn't call the parent constructor, add `parent::__construct($username, $password, $salt, $roles);` to the begining of the construcor and retest

Comment: same error after adding the parent constructor... :( This time its on line 59

Comment: Argh, I can't think of a way to debug this, sorry it has been a while since I used Symfony, hope someone will help!

Comment: I need to check thoroughly again on implementing roles in symfony. i'm new to it so I'm still on the way.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are passing a string for your role. Pass it as an array!

```
public function __construct($user, $credentials, $providerKey, array $roles = array())
```

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/UsernamePasswordToken.php#L34

So if the role was `Admin`, try passing `array('admin')`.

Comment: I have updated my question, If I pass "return array('admin');" in getRole function, Now login is working but on register page it is showing error "The value of type "array" cannot be converted to a valid array key."

Comment: Ah, maybe it is looking for an array with a key like array('somekey' => 'somevalue').

Comment: Hmm. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/AbstractToken.php#L43 Looks like a string should have been ok! I'll Check the Role __construct() method

Comment: Strange, a string should have definitely been ok https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Role/Role.php

Comment: I'm still stuck on this issue...not able to figure out whats wrong with the code.

Comment: I have two roles that user select while registering, ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN, so as per the current implementation, if a user is registering, he can be either admin user or normal user. Just want to ask do I have to create separate table for roles ?

Comment: You could, but I don't think it's necessary