# TypeError when rendering navbar in Symfony 4

Tags: php, html, symfony, authentication, symfony4

I've got a `TypeError` in in TraceableVoter constructor in **Symfony 4.2.2** project when rendering index page with user navbar added. Security.yaml file is attached to this question below.

All project source is a complete replica of Symfony 4 course from Udemy.
`TypeError` goes with the following Traceback:

> Argument 4 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\VoteEvent::__construct() must be of the type integer, null given, called in /home/vagrant/symfony-01/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/Voter/TraceableVoter.php on line 40
>   Twig_Environment->render('micro-post/index.html.twig', array('posts' => array(object(MicroPost), object(MicroPost), object(MicroPost), object(MicroPost), object(MicroPost), object(MicroPost), object(MicroPost), object(MicroPost), object(MicroPost), object(MicroPost))))
>   in src/Controller/MicroPostController.php (line 81)

**nav bar from intex.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md sticky-top bg-dark p-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0"
       href="{{ path('micro_post_index') }}">Micro Post App</a>
    <div class="w-100 order-1 order-md-0">
        <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
            {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
                <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('micro_post_add') }}">Add new</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="order-2 order-md-1">
        <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
            {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
                <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
                    <a class="nav-link"
                       href="#">{{ app.user.fullName }}</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
                    <a class="nav-link"
                       href="{{ path('security_logout') }}">Sign out</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
                    <a class="nav-link"
                       href="{{ path('security_login') }}">Sign in</a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**Handling index page in MicroPostController.php**

```
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="micro_post_index")
     * */
    public function index()
    {
        $html = $this->twig->render('micro-post/index.html.twig', ['posts' => $this->microPostRepository->findAll()]);
        return new Response($html);
    }
```

**security.yaml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: security_login
                login_path: security_login
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                default_target_path: micro_post_index
            logout:
                path: security_logout
                target: micro_post_index
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/micro-post, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

**This is not a duplicate question.** converting roles `toArray()` **does NOT** solve my issue.
Here is full stacktrace:

```
TypeError:
Argument 4 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\VoteEvent::__construct() must be of the type integer, null given, called in /home/vagrant/symfony-01/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/Voter/TraceableVoter.php on line 40

  at vendor/symfony/security-core/Event/VoteEvent.php:31
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\VoteEvent->__construct(object(ExampleVoter), object(Request), array('ROLE_USER'), null)
     (vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/Voter/TraceableVoter.php:40)
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\TraceableVoter->vote(object(AnonymousToken), object(Request), array('ROLE_USER'))
     (vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/AccessDecisionManager.php:73)
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AccessDecisionManager->decideAffirmative(object(AnonymousToken), array('ROLE_USER'), object(Request))
     (vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/AccessDecisionManager.php:60)
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AccessDecisionManager->decide(object(AnonymousToken), array('ROLE_USER'), object(Request))
     (vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/TraceableAccessDecisionManager.php:61)
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\TraceableAccessDecisionManager->decide(object(AnonymousToken), array('ROLE_USER'), object(Request))
     (vendor/symfony/security-http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:67)
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AccessListener->handle(object(GetResponseEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Debug/WrappedListener.php:46)
  at Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\WrappedListener->handle(object(GetResponseEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Debug/TraceableFirewallListener.php:35)
  at Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener->handleRequest(object(GetResponseEvent), object(Generator))
     (vendor/symfony/security-http/Firewall.php:90)
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/security-bundle/EventListener/FirewallListener.php:48)
  at Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\EventListener\FirewallListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:111)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(EventDispatcher))
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:212)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:44)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:145)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:126)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:67)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:198)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (public/index.php:25)
```

Comment: Did you check this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009476/catchable-fatal-error-argument-4-passed-to-usernamepasswordtoken-construct It might be the same problem, can you show your User entity ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 4 passed to UsernamePasswordToken::\_\_construct() must be an array, null given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009476/catchable-fatal-error-argument-4-passed-to-usernamepasswordtoken-construct)

Answer (score 2):

In have some remarks about your MicroPostController.php (the index actions),

- When you render the template view, you have just to do `$this->render('path_to_template)`; instead of `$this->twig->render('path_to_template)`
- You don't have to pass your Twig view to any variable and return Response()
- If your want to use an ***Entity Repository*** in Symfony 4.x, use the ***Dependency Injections*** so your ***index*** takes a paramaters like public

`function index(MicroPostRepository $microPostRepository) {}`

Then your controller must be like this

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="micro_post_index")
 * */
public function index(MicroPostRepository $microPostRepository)
{
    return $this->render('micro-post/index.html.twig', [
        'posts' => $microPostRepository->findAll()
    ]);
}
```

Finally, to resolve the problem check your **User Entity** and replace your ***Roles getters*** to

```
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles->toArray();
}
```

To create an User Entity the best practice is to do it with the ***Maker Bundle*** and avoid this error

```
php bin/console make:user
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working. First of all, `return $this->roles->toArray();` does not affect this error because $roles is already of type `ArrayCollection`. And $microPostRepository is an attribute of MicroPostController so I pass it like $this->$microPostRepository

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue. There is `$result` variable in `TraceableVoter->vote` method. It should return an integer. I dumped this variable, and there was really `int 0`. But for some reasons, the `VoteEvent` class takes this value as null. Therefore, after the 38th line in `TraceableVoter`, I added `intval($result);`.

```
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $subject, array $attributes)
{
    $result = $this->voter->vote($token, $subject, $attributes);

    $result = intval($result);//here

    $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch('debug.security.authorization.vote', new VoteEvent($this->voter, $subject, $attributes, $result));

    return $result;
}
```

I am new to symfony, so I don’t know if my decision was right, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong path to app.js was given - `build\js\app.js`.
Solved by adding a valid `app.js` path to the base template:

**base.html.twig**

```
...

{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you **don't have** a Voter with a function inside that **has no return**.

This error occurs when your voting process has a result of null.

Answer (score 0):

I think **Alex_B** is right. and problem was is Voter - that it is returns null. If u r on lesson 43 (is_granted), u mast have ExampleVoter with empty method vote. So i've just made it to return 0 of false like this:

*App\Security\ExampleVoter.php*

```
namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\VoterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

class ExampleVoter implements VoterInterface
{

  public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $subject, array $attributes)
  {

  return false;

  }
}
```

and everything come normal. I'm also new to symfony and hope it will fix ur problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the default symfony setup, may be there is override for VoterInterface and you could find it in src/Security/ExampleVoter.php

```
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $subject, array $attributes)
    {
        // TODO: Implement vote() method.
    }
```

Here is the problem either to return 0; or delete the folder to stop overriding.